# change row into column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a table that looks like this

```
TO : dave   
date:04-jan-2016   
text: hello how are you?

From:Dave  
date: 04-jan-2016  
text: im good and you?  

to: dave  
date: 04-jan-2016  
text: what are you up to
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
to ----------From-------------- Date----------------- Text  
Dave ..........................  04-jan-2016 ......... hello how are you?  
.............Dave .............. 04-jan-2016 ......... Im good and you?
Dave  .........................  04-jan-2016  ........ What are you up to
```

Comment: need a bit more info on your source data.  Is each row in one cell, so it one column of data?  is the : a separator and stuff after is in a second column?  this is really looking like more of a job for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) and some basic maths to provide relative positioning to the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a). The [COLUMN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) can select a lookup option from the [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907). The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) supplies the error control that converts `#N/A` returns to zero-length strings.

Put the following standard formula into a cell with sufficient blank space to the right and down.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(REPLACE(INDEX(INDEX($A:$A, 1+((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)):INDEX($A:$A, 3+((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)), MATCH(CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A), "to:*", "from:*", "date:*", "text:*"), INDEX($A:$A, 1+((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)):INDEX($A:$A, 3+((ROW(1:1)-1)*4)), 0)), 1, CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A), 3, 5, 5, 5), TEXT(,))), TEXT(,))
```

Fill both right and down to catch all available entries.

[image: from_Dave]